# joining two datatable which have dynamic column using stored procedure in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server

How can I join (inner) the two datatable dt1 and dt2 that have dynamic coloumn. using stored procedure in dynamic sql.

dt1 contains

```
emp id empname SickLeave  Casualleave
 1      h        1
```

dt2 contains

```
empid empname SickLeave Casualleave
1       h       5         5
```

I have to show output like

```
empid empname SickLeave Casualleave
1       h      1/5         0/5
```

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamic column`?

Comment: dynamic coloumn means sick leave,casual leave are not fixed its depend upon database.we can add onther leave also in datbase then another leave type should also shows in output.

Comment: but in both datatables column would always same right?

Comment: @user2516261 Have you had any chance to try the solution I proposed?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`STUFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) like this:

```
WITH CTE(empid, empname, SickLeave, Casualleave)
AS (SELECT * FROM dt1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dt2
   )
SELECT distinct empid, empname
, SickLeave = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' / ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[SickLeave])
           FROM CTE b 
           WHERE b.empid = a.empid
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
, Casualleave = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' / ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[Casualleave])
           FROM CTE C 
           WHERE C.empid = a.empid
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM CTE a
GROUP BY Empid, empname;
```

Output:

```
| EMPID | EMPNAME | SICKLEAVE | CASUALLEAVE |
---------------------------------------------
|     1 |       h |     1 / 5 |       0 / 5 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c392d/1)

Comment: I can't write sick leave =......or casual leave=.....code because these leave type are not fixed its vary according to leave type table data . in this time only to two leave type are available in database ,ick leave and casual leave. but leave type valu can be cahnged according to database

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic SQL...

```
SELECT emp_id
     , empname
     , dt1_sickleave   + '/' + dt2_sickleave   As sickleave
     , dt1_casualleave + '/' + dt2_casualleave As casualleave
FROM   (
        SELECT Coalesce(dt1.emp_id, dt2.emp_id) As emp_id
             , Coalesce(dt1.empname, dt2.empname) As empname
             , Cast(Coalesce(dt1.sickleave  , 0) As varchar(10)) As dt1_sickleave
             , Cast(Coalesce(dt1.casualleave, 0) As varchar(10)) As dt1_casualleave
             , Cast(Coalesce(dt2.sickleave  , 0) As varchar(10)) As dt2_sickleave
             , Cast(Coalesce(dt2.casualleave, 0) As varchar(10)) As dt2_casualleave
        FROM   dt1
         FULL
          JOIN dt2
            ON dt2.emp_id = dt1.emp_id
       ) As x
```

Comment: but the coloumn name are dynamic depend upon the database value means sick leave and casual leave are not fixed .

Comment: In which case I strongly recommend you rethink your output requirements. I would output multiple rows per emp_id; one row per status with the corresponding value (if available). If you need to display the results of this "horizontally" then that's a job for your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe this will do what you want. This query gets all the column names from `sys.columns` named like `'%leave%'` where the table is either `dt1`or `dt2` and builds a dynamic query that it then executes. It relies on the sys.columns and sys.tables (which might be bad) and has the source table names `dt1`and `dt2`hard coded.

In my opinion this is not a good solution, and the correct solution to the problem might be to alter the data model so that `leave`becomes an entity of it's own.

I've commented out the `EXECUTE`at the end and left the `PRINT`in so you can see what the query will do before executing it.

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',' + name + '', '' + name + '') FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    'CAST(ISNULL(dt1.' + name + ',0) AS VARCHAR) + ''/'' + CAST(dt2.' + name + ' AS VARCHAR) AS ' + name + ' ' AS name 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE NAME LIKE '%leave%' 
AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE name IN ('dt1', 'dt2'))) LeaveColumns

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT 
dt1.empid, 
dt1.empname, ' + @Columns + ' 
FROM dt1 
INNER JOIN dt2 ON dt1.empid=dt2.empid'    

PRINT @SQL -- Uncomment to see the query which will be run
--EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

For me this gives the following output (with a slightly altered table structure where I included more `leave`columns):

```
SELECT 
dt1.empid, 
dt1.empname, 
CAST(ISNULL(dt1.casualleave,0) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(dt2.casualleave AS VARCHAR) AS casualleave ,
CAST(ISNULL(dt1.sickleave,0) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(dt2.sickleave AS VARCHAR) AS sickleave ,
CAST(ISNULL(dt1.someotherleave,0) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(dt2.someotherleave AS VARCHAR) AS someotherleave ,
CAST(ISNULL(dt1.yetanotherleave,0) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(dt2.yetanotherleave AS VARCHAR) AS yetanotherleave  
FROM dt1 
INNER JOIN dt2 ON dt1.empid=dt2.empid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.[empid],t1.[empname],
Cast(COALESCE(t1.[SickLeave],0) as char)
     +'/'
     +cast(COALESCE(t2.[SickLeave],0) as char) as SickLeave,
Cast(COALESCE(t1.[Casualleave],0) as char)
+'/'
+cast(COALESCE(t2.[Casualleave],0) as char) as Casualleave
from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on 
t1.[empid]=t2.[empid];
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94c58/6)